# adding MySQL Query to PHPMYAdmin

Tags: .net, mysql

I have created a project in visual studio with MYSQL using MYSQL Workbench.  It works fine.  Then I go to my hosting provider and try to add the stored proc

Error
SQL query:

CREATE PROCEDURE spLogin_VerifyUser( IN User VARCHAR( 50 ) , IN Pass VARCHAR( 50 ) , OUT ChurchID INT ) BEGIN DECLARE ChurchIDTemp INT DEFAULT 0;

MySQL said:

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

when I try to add the following stored proc:

```
create procedure spLogin_VerifyUser(IN User VARCHAR(50),IN Pass VARCHAR(50),OUT ChurchID INT)
begin
DECLARE ChurchIDTemp INT DEFAULT 0;
select idchurch into ChurchIDTemp FROM loginusers
WHERE Username=User and Password=Pass;
select IFNULL(ChurchIDTemp,0) into ChurchID;
end
;;
```

Comment: I am using phpmyadmin btw to try to add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
delimiter |
create procedure spLogin_VerifyUser(IN User VARCHAR(50),IN Pass VARCHAR(50),OUT ChurchID INT)
begin
    DECLARE ChurchIDTemp INT DEFAULT 0;
    select idchurch into ChurchIDTemp FROM loginusers
    WHERE Username=User and Password=Pass;

    select IFNULL(ChurchIDTemp,0) into ChurchID;
end;
|
```

Comment: juergen D: I tried your answer and got this error:#1044 - Access denied for user 'getre_admin'@'%' to database 'getreal2_churchweb'

Comment: @ChrisNorris: Are you running this script with enough rights? Are you using root user?

Comment: I am not using root..its a shared mysql server

Comment: it turned out to be the isp's permissions..they didnt allow stored procedures created by users..they had to run the create scripts themselves

Answer (score 0):

Is it the full version of MySQL or the Community version?

Community version is free but does not permit stored procedures.

(I had the same problem a few years back)

Comment: I use the community version and it works with stored procedures. Maybe your problem was a much older version of MySQL

Comment: Very possibly! Check the delimiter answer above, looks a good bet to me.

Comment: The issue they said was that according to their  "rules" my db name has to be part of the stored proc name.  Although ive tried this and still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This is a commonly faced error.

As you may already know mySQL allows procedures but phpMyAdmin does let you design them. Now if you've written one elsewhere and want phpMyAdmin simple to execute it then ensure this:

1. You do not have the free community version of mySQL as it does not allow stored procedures. I believe this is a compatibility issue between different versions and phpMyAdmin. Check below for a possible solution.

Refer to this: http://tycoontalk.freelancer.com/the-database-forum/117270-phpmyadmin-and-procedures.html

In the PhpMyAdmin list of databases should be information_schema. In it is a table name ROUTINES. You query it by issuing a

```
select ROUTINE_NAME from ROUTINES;
```

This will output a list of Stored Procedure names. To see a procedure, run the query

```
show create procdure [procedure name from above select]
```